# Transform data frame some columns into rows

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, reshape2, tidyverse

**DATA**

i have a data frame like this:

```
 id weigth temp_s1 temp_s2
  1     50       2       7
  2     51       3       8
  3     52       4       9
  4     53       5      10
  5     54       6      11
```

**What i want**

I would like to obtain this:

```
     id weigth  temp    value
      1     50  temp_s1     2
      1     50  temp_s2     7
      1     51  temp_s1     3
      1     51  temp_s2     8
      1     52  temp_s1     4
      1     52  temp_s2     9
      1     53  temp_s1     5
      1     53  temp_s2     10
      1     54  temp_s1     6
      1     54  temp_s2     11
```

Comment: Could you post the result of dput on your df?

Comment: Can't check without data to try on but `dat %>% tidyr::gather(temp, value, -weight)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `melt` function from `reshape2` package as follows:

```
melt(df, c("id", "weight"))
```